# Buildung a dev machine with one vagrant line

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

Im trying to setup a environment where a new developer has only to install vagrant and virtualbox and then is able to create a dev vm with only one line.

My first approach was to create a vagrant box (which worked pretty well) and then edit the Vagrantfile inside of the .box file, but the content will not be merged in the local vagrant file.

My second approach was to set up a chef server and let the vagrant box execute the remote cookbook on every boot, but i do not really need the chef server.

My goal is to drop one single file on a network storage and let all new developers clone their machines from that one file.

Some ideas? 
Kind Regards, deen

Comment: Use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys i missed the --vagrantfile option @ the package program. I now included my vagrantfile by this parameter and all works finde.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably wouldn't want to use a Chef Server/client set up, but Vagrant supports Chef Solo or you could look at using Packer to build your own images.